# Error: laravel form syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, laravel

FatalErrorException in fa3184558a5755c9fa96bb02557f41ee8de6082c.php line 46:
syntax error, unexpected ';'
the error at line 46
and line 46 in this form   section_name; ?>

- List item

  ```
  {!!Form::open(["url"=>"library/$section->id","method"=>"patch"])!!}
  <td> {!! Form::text("section_name",$section->section_name !!}</td>
  ```
- List item

  ```
  <?php echo Form::open(["url"=>"library/$section->id","method"=>"patch"]) ?>

  <td> <?php echo Form::text("section_name",$section->section_name; ?></td>

      <td> 
          <span class="label label-default"><?php echo e($section->books_total); ?> </span><!-- to display lable and total the books-->
           </td>
  ```

  this is my first project

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and show us what line it's referring to when asking questions like this.

Comment: FatalErrorException in fa3184558a5755c9fa96bb02557f41ee8de6082c.php line 46:
syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: here this error line 46

Comment: here this error line 46 at <td> <?php echo Form::text("section_name",$section->section_name; ?></td>

Comment: You should edit your original post in stead of putting it in the comments. You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<td> <?php echo Form::text("section_name",$section->section_name; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td> <?php echo Form::text("section_name",$section->section_name); ?></td>
```

A `Form::text(...` needs a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)` right before the `;`, apparently on line 46.